# Nonabelian variants of the Breen-Deligne resolution

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, derived-functors, condensed-mathematics

The Breen-Deligne resolution is an unusual functorial resolution of an abelian group A by finite direct sums of free abelian groups of the form $\Bbb Z[A^n] = Free_{Ab}(A^n)$. It makes several appearances in the condensed-mathematics documents to prove tractability of certain homological calculations.

That's an abelian situation. Here is a *nonabelian* analogue: does there exist a functorial resolution of a group $G$ by a simplicial group, levelwise a finite coproduct of groups of the form $Free_{Grp}(G^n)$? (As a reality check, taking abelianization would give us a functorial chain complex, levelwise a finite direct sum of free abelian groups $\Bbb Z[G^n]$, whose homology is (shifted) group homology. Those do exist -- homogeneous or inhomogeneous chains.)

More generally, are there straightforward conditions on a Lawvere theory $\cal T$ to ensure that a $\cal T$-algebra $M$ has a functorial resolution by finite coproducts of free $\cal T$-algebras $Free_{\cal T}(M^n)$?

(One can obtain resolutions by such objects using a general method of resolving the identity in a functor category; it's really the finiteness that's the critical question.)

Comment: I think I can accomplish something weaker, but maybe similar in spirit to what you are asking for. Namely, realize $G$ as a filtered simplicial group, where each stage of the filtration is obtained from the previous one by a pushout along a map between free groups of the kind that you describe. The idea is to use the bar construction Bar$(F, M, G)$, where $F$ and $M$ are the free group and the free monoid monad respectively, and then use the natural filtration of $M$ to filter the bar construction. If it sounds useful, I could try to write an answer with more details.

Comment: @GregoryArone Thanks! I think I get the gist of it; the use of the free monoid is handy here, and it certainly gives you the general type of resolution (I can imagine somehow inductively getting control of which parts of $M^{(p)}(G)$ are degenerate and building that way). I can imagine something like this working if you've got a simplicial operad...

Comment: (I believe that I now know how to adapt the argument to give a proof, at least for groups; but it would take enough effort to write here that, unless someone else has an application, I'm going to take a pass for now.)